# How does this Barbarian build generate fury?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

There's a Barbarian build on [this site](http://diablo.somepage.com/popular/barbarian#builds) with the following skills:

#### Active Skills:

- Hammer of the Ancients - Smash
- Overpower - Killing Spree
- Wrath of the Berserker - Thrive on Chaos
- Whirlwind - Hurricane
- Battle Rage - Into the Fray
- Sprint - Run Like the Wind

#### Passive Skills:

- Bloodthirst
- Weapons Master
- Ruthless

None of those are fury generating skills. So how does the barb generate fury?

Comment: You could take a Mighty Weapon with gives 1 Fury per Hit by Weapons Master

Comment: that looks like a left over from 1.8, lots of barbs may not have updated their skills yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This build worked prior to patch 2.0.

The listed build is out of date - *Into the Fray* has changed since that time and no longer generates fury on crit.

---

Simple!

**Battle Rage - Into the Fray.**

> While under the effects of Battle Rage, Critical Hits have a chance to generate 15 additional Fury.
> <sub>- [Diablo Wiki - Battle Rage](http://www.diablowiki.net/Battle_Rage)</sub>

I don't know why, but the site your providing does not gives the true definition of the Skill. :/

It is a very common way (if not the most used) to build fury as a barbarian. In fact, Most High-end barbarian players will stack AS (attack speed) as their priority stat. The Goal is to hit as much time as possible. With *Whirlwind*, the tornadoes of *Sprint - Run Like the Wind* and *Overpower - Killing Spree*, You hit so much often when in crowded groups of enemies that you generate tons of Fury. Spending it is also very important, this is why spamming *Overpower*, *Battle Rage* and *Sprint*. Consistently generating and spending your fury helps you keep your *Wrath of the Berserker* as long as you have something to hit.

The *Hammer of the Ancients - Smash* stands only for those High health elites. It is also a very good fury spender.

Here is a [very good article](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-class-forums/barbarian-bastions-keep/47713-1-0-6-barbarian-popular-builds-hints-and-bis-gear) of different builds of the barbarian. It is a bit old but you can still learn plenty of things, such as the proper ways of Generating and spending fury.

Comment: Battle Rage - Into the Fray was reworked in patch 2.0.0 and no longer generates fury on crit.  The linked wiki is out of date while the diablo.somepage article has the updated skill info.

Comment: yea this is out dated.  Battle rage ItF no longer gives fury.

Answer (score 6):

That build was used prior to patch 2 exactly as Sinity has suggested.  However, with recent changes to skills, the build listed there will currently not generate fury outside of normal attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of (it would also be worth inspecting gear):

Barbarians generate fury by taking damage. I am not sure the exact formula for how that works, but with enough toughness a Barb can stand inside a group of monsters and generate fury quickly.